# Name the fictional crime

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> The motive
>
> ```
> AṠT ẠTIONS ḄJECT ENTI
> ETṚE HAṄK ṄITED ORṬH
> OU RİENTED
> ```
>
> The weaponry
>
> ```
> ANGĖ ẸLATIONS ERVİCE EX̣AS
> LḊ LİA NGLIṢH NSTRUṀENTS
> NTEṚ ONG ROVỊDER UBLIC
> ```
>
> The victim
>
> ```
> ANḊS ARBỌN ECOṘD ẸRSONAL
> ETHER ḢEODORE IBER ỊNK
> LCOḢOLICS NTERṄET MERIC̣AN
> OOSEVẸLT XPRESṠ NỌNYMOUS
> ```

Name the fictional crime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crime is ...

> ... armed robbery.

Each word in the list ...

> ... is missing its first letter. There is an even number of words in each list and the (completed) words can be matched to form pairs. These pairs are common phrases that can be abbreviated by the (missing) initial letters, e.g. United Nations is abbreviated as UN. In some cases, the couple forms a single word, that is still abrreviated by the first two letters of the segments, e.g. centimetre is abbreviated as cm.
>
> ```
> CM   CENTI-METṚE         PR   PUBLIC RẸLATIONS      CF   CARBỌN FIBER
> OO   OḄJECT ORİENTED     IA   INTEṚ ALİA            AA   ALCOḢOLICS ANỌNYMOUS
> UN   UṄITED NẠTIONS      SP   SERVİCE PROVỊDER      PR   PẸRSONAL RECOṘD
> NE   NORṬH-EAṠT          TI   TEX̣AS INSTRUṀENTS     TR   TḢEODORE ROOSEVẸLT
> TY   THAṄK YOU           OE   OLḊ ENGLIṢH           AE   AMERIC̣AN EXPRESṠ
>                          LR   LONG RANGĖ            IL   INTERṄET LỊNK
>                                                     NL   NETHER-LANḊS
> ```
>
> Each pair has one word with a dot above and one word with a dot below, but two words in each section don't have a dot. I didn't see the significance of the dots, but OP told me in the comments and now it's quite obvious to me: The dots determine the order of the pairs: Each dot below a letter lines up with a dot above a letter in the next line. (The hyphens are just there to enforce the alignment; I guess the alignment is also why the puzzle uses a monospace font.)
>
>  Anyway, we can read the abbreviations column-wise and get the motive **count money**, the weapons **pistol** and **rapier** and the victim **Captain Farrell**.

These facts ...

> ... point to [Whiskey in the Jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whiskey_in_the_Jar), an Irish folk song made popular by The Dubliners and other bands. There are slight variations in the lyrics in each interpretation, but the general plot is the same. Here's the first stanza:
>
>      *As I was a goin' over the far famed Kerry mountains*
>      *I met with Captain Farrell and his money he was counting*
>      *I first produced my pistol and I then produced my rapier*
>      *Saying "Stand and deliver" for he were a bold deceiver*

Comment: Correct! The dots are rot13[thvqrf gb gur pbeerpg beqre, ohg vg bayl jbexf orsber nqqvat gur zvffvat yrggref (RAGV RGER rgp).] I admit it would have made more sense to add them in the format you've used in your answer, though...

Comment: Ah! Now I see how it works and it's quite obvious. Too bad I didn't get what the dots mean -- they were the most intriguing part of another fine puzzle from you.

Answer (score 2):

Very partial solution, but it looks like...

> Words are missing their first letter, and they can be matched in pairs.

**The motive:**

> **U**ṄITED **N**ẠTIONS
> **C**ENTI **M**ETṚE 
> **T**HAṄK **Y**OU
> **O**ḄJECT **O**RİENTED
> **N**ORṬH **E**AṠT

**The weaponry:**

> **T**EX̣AS **I**NSTRUṀENTS
> **O**LḊ **E**NGLIṢH
> **S**ERVİCE **P**ROVỊDER
> **L**ONG **R**ANGĖ
> **P**UBLIC **R**ẸLATIONS
> **I**NTEṚ **A**LİA

**The motive:**

> **T**ḢEODORE **R**OOSEVẸLT
> **A**LCOḢOLICS **A**NỌNYMOUS
> **A**MERIC̣AN **E**XPRESṠ
> **C**ARBỌN **F**IBER
> **N**ETHER **L**ANḊS
> **I**NTERṄET **L**ỊNK
> **P**ẸRSONAL **R**ECOṘD

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer

The Ideology

> The first letter was missing from each word. Not sure what to do with the dots though

The motive

AṠT ẠTIONS ḄJECT ENTI

> **v/f**ast **r**ations **o**bject **s**enti

ETṚE HAṄK ṄITED ORṬH

> **m**etre **t**hank **u**nited **n**orth

OU RİENTED

> **y**ou **o**riented

The weaponry

ANGĖ ẸLATIONS ERVİCE EX̣AS

> **r**ange **r**elations **s**ervice **t**exas

LḊ LİA NGLIṢH NSTRUṀENTS

> **o**ld **i**lia **e**nglish **i**nstruments

NTEṚ ONG ROVỊDER UBLIC

> **e**nter **l?**ong **p**rovider **p**ublic

The Victim

ANḊS ARBỌN ECOṘD ẸRSONAL

> **h/s**ands **c**arbon **r**ecord **p**ersonal

ETHER ḢEODORE IBER ỊNK

> **t/n**ether **T**heodore **f?**iber **l?**ink

LCOḢOLICS NTERṄET MERIC̣AN

> **a**lcoholics **i**nternet **a**merican --> AIA?

OOSEVẸLT XPRESṠ NỌNYMOUS

> **R**oosevelt **e**xpress **a**nonymous -->rea?